# When is the earliest you can dynamically add JS/CSS and apply them

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dynamic

I was wondering when is the earliest you can dynamically add and apply JS/CSS, I am thinking that is has to be done when the document is ready so document.ready. The reason I am asking this is I am not sure if this will be the fastest approach, and will performance be an issue. So if there is a way for me to load the JS/CSS while the document is loading that would be great, but if not I though so.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? JS is loaded when the `script` tag it is encountered in the HTML, which is usually *in* the document, so before it is completely loaded.

Comment: I need to load different css and js if the user is accessing my site via a mobile device (smartphone/tablet). And that is exactly what I mean, is there a way for me to change the document dynamically during the load process instead of after? Cause I can do it after using document.ready, or maybe listen to a event that tells me that the JS are being loaded?

Comment: You can put a `script` tag at the beginning of `head` and add `style` elements to `head` for example. You don't have to wait until the whole DOM is loaded, only the part that you need to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages are processed top-to-bottom. The earliest you can RUN JS is to have an inline script block in the HEAD. If this script needs to access the DOM though, you're out of luck because that is loaded later on.

Comment: The DOM will always exist when the script is run. There may be no more than an `html` element, a `head` element, and the 'script' element in the DOM when it runs though.

Comment: This is true. The DOM is there, but will usually be empty at this stage.